# Regular expression to match phone number

Tags: regex

I am trying to come up with a regular expression that will invalidate the following (phone numbers)

- Less than 10 numbers
- Number starting with +61 but are less than 11 numbers excluding ' + ' sign
- Number starting with +61 but are exceeding 11 numbers excluding ' + ' sign
- Number starting with 0061 but are less than 13 numbers
- Number starting with 0061 but are exceeding 13 numbers
- Number starting with any other country code than 0061 or +61 but are less than 7 numbers

So far I have come up with

```
^((\+|00)\d{1,3}[- ]?)?\d{10}$
```

However this fails (does not catch the following)

- Number starting with +61 but are exceeding 11 numbers excluding ' + ' sign
- Number starting with +61 but are exceeding 11 numbers excluding ' + ' sign

Any help on this please

Comment: Why the down vote? It's clear enough what the problem is and they've shown what they've tried and where they're having trouble.

Comment: Why other countries have only 7 digits?

Comment: which programming language are you doing this in? Asking because their regexpr may have slight differences.

Comment: @tmpdev Greetings from BrisVegas.  Can you perhaps help me to build a battery of test strings (phone numbers) which sufficiently isolates what you want to match/mismatch?  Here's what I've started with: https://regex101.com/r/23BWKz/4  I am still operating with a fair amount of uncertainty.  Please build upon that and edit your question so we can work toward a resolution.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone numbers could not contain spaces (as your regex indicates), backtracking seems to be your problem.

Consider this part of your regex: `(\d{1,3}[- ]?)?\d`

The thing here is the optional dash/space string. If that won't match, you'll end up with a list of consecutive numbers. As the engine wants to find a match, it will consider part of the country code as the phone number or vice versa.

Example (the space is to differentiate): `+1 23456789012` could also be written as `+123 456789012`. According to your regex, both will match, but you probably only want to get a match for the first phone number.

**Update 1**

This regex *validates* the phone numbers according to your list of criterias:

`^(?:(?:\+61[- ]?\d{9}|0061[- ]?\d{9})|(?:\+|00)(?!(61))\d{1,6})$`

It has basically two parts:

- `(?:\+61[- ]?\d{9}|0061[- ]?\d{9})` validates points 1,2,3,4,5
- `(?:\+|00)(?!(61))\d{1,6})` validates point 6

Remember that the length of the whole number depends on the [country code](https://countrycode.org/).

Examples: https://regex101.com/r/23BWKz/3

Comment: actually the expression you have given does not match the following +61424323547  Plus it also matches the following +614245456435 which it should not.